# How to make the browser displays this hexadecimal value (in GBK)?

Tags: php, gbk

If i do `echo(0xbf5c);` it renders `0xbf5c`. But it normally correspond to a chinese letter. How can i make this latter displayed ?

Thanks

Comment: Nope, it displays [`48988`](https://3v4l.org/URTUH)... I think you've skipped a few steps there between a number in hex notation and a character.

Comment: What character is that supposed to correspond to?

Comment: try pack("H*" , $hex_string); where $hex_string is your hex string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split the character into individual bytes and use PHP's \xhh (character with hex code hh) escape character in a double-quoted string:

```
header("Content-Type: text/plain; charset=GBK");
echo "\xbf\x5c";
```

You won't need the `header` line if your webserver is already configured to use the GBK charset.